# Effect of brighter suns on eyes on a creature on a world orbiting a red dwarf

Tags: biology, planets, environment

I know that red dwarf stars are dimmer than ours. But I also know that red dwarf stars emit a lot of infrared light, so creatures on a world orbiting it would have eyes that see infrared light.

If a space faring species from this world traveled near a brighter sun, would they have to protect their eyes, or would they not need to because they see mainly in infrared? Or would brighter suns give off more infrared light than red dwarf stars?

Comment: Our very own Sun emits a lot of infrared light... which you can feel yourself if you go out in a sunny day.

Comment: It's not just the eyes you have to worry about. We can't see in ultraviolet, but prolonged exposure will do a lot of damage to our skin. A space faring species adapted to the MUCH lower levels of radiation from a red dwarf would be likely to suffer severe sunburn if they weren't protected.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is "if they were adapted for lower light levels, they would have to protect their eyes".  Brighter stars emit more energy all through the EMR spectrum, *including* the infared.

However, the intensity experienced during a creature's evolution would be less a function of the star's spectral range, and more the proximity of the planet to the star - and life is more likely to evolve (based on a sample size of 1!) on a planet that receives about the same amount of surface energy as Earth does.

So your hypothetical creatures from a red dwarf system would probably be fine on a planet in a yellow dwarf system because the [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) of their stars would be roughly equivalent.

Comment: Heck. Totally forgot about proximity to star as a factor. Now I feel stupid about asking this obvious question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a graph that shows the proportion of the total radiated energy from a [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) contributed by specific wavelengths (more or less).

[image: wavelength spectral radiance from a black bod]

You can see that as the temperature of an object rises, the proportion of the *total* emitted radiation that falls into infrared wavelengths is smaller than for cooler objects, but because the *total* amount of radiation is so much greater the hot object will produce more IR than the cooler object. For reference, 3000K is an M-class star type temperature (Barnard's Star is 3134K), and 5000K is a cool yellow/warm orange type temperature (Epsilon Eridani is 5084K). Our Sun is a bit hotter still.

Whether or not eye protection is required of course depends on a bunch of factors, but all else being equal (distance, atmosphere, weather, etc) they would indeed need it if they were visiting a world around a hotter star.

> so creatures on a world orbiting it would have eyes that see infrared light.

There's a secondary requirement here, that the environment that they live in needs to be somewhat cooler than Earth. The longer the wavelength you want to detect, the more prone you are to thermal noise turning your vision into a fuzzy mess (see this article  on [why animals don't have infrared vision](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2011-06-animals-dont-infrared-vision.html) for a little more information). I'm not sure how much colder they'd need to be than Earth comfortable ambient, but it is an issue you should bear in mind.

Visiting a world around a brighter sun might blind them, but they might have more pressing issues regarding being cooked to death...

Comment: The world they live on is indeed pretty cold. To cold for life as we know it, but not for this particular species.